# Initial Value proof fails- where did I go wrong

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Been working on a rate of change problem relating change in fluid volume to the change in the central angle between the center of the tank and the point at which the fluid touches the sidewall (${\theta}$) as the liquid is drained. I'll spare you the work. But the derivative works out to $$ {dV_{fluid}=2LR^2(1+1/2\cos2\theta)d\theta}$$

Working the differential equation  I get $${dV_{fluid}/2LR^2=(1+1/2\cos2\theta) d\theta}$$

multiplying by 2 yields $${dV_{fluid}/LR^2=(2+\cos2\theta)d\theta}$$
Now that much I know I can get away with. My question is...does the rest of this work to define the new angle ${\theta}$ as the fluid is drained?
Continuing...$${dV_{fluid}/(LR^2d\theta)=2+\cos2\theta}$$
$${dV_{fluid}/(LR^2d\theta)-2=\cos2\theta}$$
So then the new angle would be? $${\theta=1/2\cos^{-1}[(1/(LR^2)dV_{fluid}/d\theta-2]}$$

The problem is that when I try to prove this with the initial value ${dV_{f}=0}$ I get $${\theta=1/2\cos^{-1}[(1/LR^2 (0))-2]}$$ so ${\theta= 1/2 cos^{-1} (-2)}$ Which is meaningless.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You have $\theta$ on one side and $d\theta$ on the other?

Comment: It is not clear what you are attempting to do. This looks like an integration rather than an ODE?

Comment: I am trying to define ${\theta}$. Because the full problem requires marking a sight gauge at ${R\sin\theta}$ for various levels in a tank.

Comment: Sorry the post wasn't clear please reread the edit.

Comment: Is your goal to get a formula for $V$ as a function of $\theta$? If not, what is your goal?

Comment: Actually my goal is to get ${\theta}$ as a function of the change in volume. From that point I can use h=R${\sin\theta}$ to mark the gauge.

Comment: If all you want is $\theta={\rm something\ involving\ }dV/d\theta$, then what you have is fine, except I'd write it differently, ${1\over LR^2}{dV\over d\theta}$ where you have $dV/(LR^2d\theta)$.

Comment: So then a better form  (more standardized) would be.. $${\theta=1/2\cos^{-1}[((1/LR^2) dV_{fluid}/d\theta)-2]}$$

Comment: I just realized a major problem with this solution. Problem was placed in the edit.